# ArgumentParser -h (help) will not work

Tags: python, command-line-arguments

I cannot get ArgumentParser to work. What's wrong with the following:

```
import argparse
parser=argparse.ArgumentParser(description='''I wish this description would output''',
                                            epilog='''Please out the epilog''')

parser.add_argument('-l', type=str, default='info', help='logging level. Default is info. Use debug if you have problems.')
args=parser.parse_args()

def main():
    print("goodbye")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #main
    main()
```

When I run `myscript -h` I see no help.

I am running Python 2.7 on Windows 7. I have Python on my path and also `pathext` set as:

```
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC;.py
```

Comment: Just a note on style, `parser.parse_args()` will run when you import your module. Is this the behaviour you want? Generally you would place your command line argument handling in `main`.

Comment: For what is worth, the code worked in Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: @Chris in other functions I have references to args.l. This is why I defined args up the top. It is like a global variable. Is this a bad idea?

Answer (score 2):

The argsparse code never actually gets executed. By executing the script from the command line, you're calling `main()`, which simply prints and exits. You have to call `parse_args()` in the `main()` function for this to work.

```
import argparse

# Personally, I think these belong in the main()
# function as well, but they don't need to be.
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description="I wish this description would output",
    epilog="Please out the epilog"
)
parser.add_argument(
    "-l",
    type=str,
    default="info",
    help="logging level. Default is info. Use debug if you have problems."
)

def main():
    args = parser.parse_args() # Parses arguments
    print("goodbye")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main() # Calls main
```

Produces:

```
~/Desktop $ python untitled.py --help
usage: untitled.py [-h] [-l L]

I wish this description would output

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  -l L        logging level. Default is info. Use debug if you have problems.

Please out the epilog
```

[jcollado](https://stackoverflow.com/users/183066/jcollado) claims your code worked fine on Ubuntu--I find this very curious.

Comment: What happens if other functions need to reference args.l?

Comment: What happens? _Programming_ happens. For example: `args = vars(parser.parse_args()); print args["l"] # prints "info"`. You can pass these values around to other functions as you like.

Comment: I was hoping to have them as global variables so I didn't have to pass them around. It makes things a bit cleaner.  Do I have to pass it around or is there anyway for each function to get it?

Comment: _Sigh_, if you _must_ use globals: http://pastebin.com/QdhG98jt ...but I think you're wrong about the code being "cleaner"--globals make code harder to understand and debug (when used improperly, which I think you are trying to do).

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Global a bad choice of word on my part. Private to the module.  You still think it's a bad idea?

Answer (score 1):

If you run this script from the command line you're going to just print 'goodbye', put the `argparse` code after `if __name__ == "__main__":`.

Answer (score 0):

OK weird answer for this.  The problem was resolved by calling the program as:

```
python myscript.py -h
```

If you add python to your path, set file associations and then just do:

```
myscript.py -h
```

it will not pick up the -h